# not abstract and does not override abstract

Tags: java, overriding

I keep on having this problem not abstract and does not override abstract
also how to apply JOptionPane

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Mycase extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JLabel text=new JLabel("Enter Name: ");
    JLabel text2=new JLabel();
    JTextField name=new JTextField(12);
    JButton press=new JButton("OK");
    JButton cancel=new JButton("CANCEL");

    public Mycase(){
        super("Name");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(150,100);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(text);
        add(press);
        add(cancel);
        add(text2);
        press.addActionListener(new press());
        cancel.addActionListener(new cancel());
    }

    class press implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            text2.setText("");
            name.setText("");
        }
    }

    class cancel implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Mycase frame=new Mycase();
    }   
}
```

Comment: you can create custom dialog with extends JDialog

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `Mycase` to implement `ActionListener` but it does not define a method with the proper signature. (Your two inner classes `press` and `cancel` do, but that doesn't fix the problem with `Mycase`.) You aren't trying to register an instance of `Mycase` as an `ActionListener`, so just change this line:

```
public class Mycase extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
```

to this:

```
public class Mycase extends JFrame {
```